# Nonnegative integer solutions to $(xy)!=x!y!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I was trying to find a way to find solutions to the factorial equation $(xy)!=x!y!$, where $x,y$ are nonnegative integers. I began with the case when $x=y$. This leads to

\begin{equation}
(x^2)!=(x!)^2
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
x^2(x^2-1)(x^2-2)!=x^2(x-1)^2(x-2)!^2\Leftrightarrow x^2(x-1)[(x+1)(x^2-2)!-(x-1)(x-2)!^2]=0\Leftrightarrow x=0,1.
\end{equation}
This case was quite easy to solve. The problem comes when considering the case when $x<y$. I suspect that the solutions for this case will be given when $x=1$ and $y>1$. Any suggestions or hints that you can give me in order to solve it for this particular case will be really appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\frac {(xy)!} {x!} >(x+1)(x+2)...(x+y)>(1)(2)...(y)=y!$ if $x,y \geq 1$ and $xy \geq x+y$. Investigate when $xy \geq x+y$ holds. [This is quite trivial!]

Comment: The inequality $xy\geq x+y$ clearly holds if and only if $x,y\geq 2$. But how does the very first inequality that you wrote can be derived? I can't visualize the way to see that it is true.

Comment: @user463019 In $(xy)!$ cancel the first $x$ factors and all  the remaining factors are at least $1$ and $(x+1)(x+2)...(x+y)$ is part of the product that gives you $(xy)!$.

Comment: But note that $x=1$ and $y>1$ is also a solution to $(xy)!=x!y!$. So how do I get to that conclusion using your observation? That inequality is strictly bigger than $y!$ not equal to $y!$, as it was proposed at the beginning.

Comment: @user463019 $x=1$ does not satisfy $xy \geq x+y$. Can you find out when  $xy <x+y$ and investigate this separately? This case is quite simple so I am leaving it to you.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to solve it with your hint! It took a lot of time to realize, but I finally did it. Obviously, the equation does not hold for $x,y\geq 2$, because we would have $(xy)!>x!y!$, so the only possibility left is when $x=1$ and $y\geq 1$ or $x\geq 1$ and $y=1$.